# Does Kotlin have a syntax for Map literals?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, literals

In JavaScript: `{foo: bar, biz: qux}`.

In Ruby: `{foo => bar, biz => qux}`.

In Java:

```
HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(foo, bar);
map.put(biz, qux);
```

Surely Kotlin can do better than Java?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can do:

```
val map = hashMapOf(
  "John" to "Doe",
  "Jane" to "Smith"
)
```

Here, [`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) is an infix function that creates a `Pair`.

Or, more abstract: use `mapOf()` like

```
val map = mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2, "c" to 3)
```

( found on [kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html) )

Comment: You probably mean `mutableMapOf()`? There's no `hashMap()` in the Kotlin runtime

Comment: @CedricBeust No, I actually meant `hashMap()` ( see here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2012/06/kotlin-m2-is-out/ ) ... but as you can see: that was 2012; and 2017, `hashMapOf()` is the way to go.

Comment: While this is very close to a map literal but I would still argue it's not the same: you still need to use function call syntax and cannot have an extra comma after the last element.

Comment: It's 2020, and I'm very frustrated that Kotlin still doesn't have map/array literals like in JS and Swift.

Answer (score 18):

There is a proposal to add them to the language:

**[KT-43871: Collection Literals](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43871)**
(formerly located at [Kotlin/KEEP #112: Collection Literals](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/112))

If this goes through, the syntax you're asking about might be like:

```kotlin
val map = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3]
```

Comment: If you let me know how this answer is not useful, I can write better ones in the future :D

Comment: Discussion is onging at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43871

Comment: it says Target version is **1.9.0**, while the Kotlin version at the time of writing this comment is **1.7.0**

Comment: why is this getting many upvotes? this is not even a real thing

Comment: @Qori It is a "real thing" and was being seriously considered at that GitHub link until Roman Elizarov took the reigns of the Kotlin project and shut down the use of GitHub for KEEPs. See the comments above yours for where this same exact feature is still being designed. I'll edit my answer to include this.